# Set a selected value by default in SelectList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to set a selected value in my select list by default.

Here I have this select list :

```
@{
    var selectList = new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Google", Value = "Google", Selected = false},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Other", Value = "Other" , Selected = true},
        }, "Value", "Text");


   var selectedValue = "Other";
}
```

Here I'am trying to set "Other" is selected by default but it is not working for me why ?

Here the Dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlDropDownList", selectList, new { @class = "css-class" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Other" is not selected by default because you have not told the SelectList which option is selected. Variable selectedValue is assigned but used no where.

Simply, use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) method signature

```
public SelectList (
  System.Collections.IEnumerable items,
  string dataValueField, 
  string dataTextField, 
  object selectedValue);
```

So your code in view will be

```
@{
        var selectList = new SelectList(
            new List<SelectListItem>
            {
               new SelectListItem {Text = "Google", Value = "Google", Selected = false},
               new SelectListItem {Text = "Other", Value = "Other" , Selected = true},
            }, "Value", "Text", "Other");

}
```

Pay attention that the last variable of the SelectList constructor is the selected value